# MVC Route static value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm not sure if this is possible using mvc routing, I haven't been able to find a similar example.

I have about 5~ controller actions that are the same method, so I'd like to refactor them into a single action.  I'd like to pass an enum value to the controller to tell it what path it should pass to lower layers.

Example:

```
public ActionResult ViewPage(int id, PageEnum page) {
    var model = MyService.GetModelForTemplate(id, page);
    return ("ViewPage", model);
}
```

Then the user could access this either through /PagesTypeOne/ViewPage/, or /PagesTypeTwo/ViewPage/.  Both routes leading to the same endpoint.

```
Route table attempt:

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "typeOne",
            url: "PagesTypeOne/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "ViewPage", id = UrlParameter.Optional, page = PageEnum.TypeOne, }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "typeTwo",
            url: "PagesTypeTwo/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "ViewPage", id = UrlParameter.Optional, page = PageEnum.TypeTwo, }
        );
```

This obviously isn't working.

Is there a way I can do something like this?  It would make my code much more concise.

Comment: Why have two different names (`typeOne` and `typeTwo`) if you're changing the id value?  I only see one argument defined in your routes, but I see the action accepting two arguments. If you're trying to pass the Enum in the global route to the page parameter, why are you calling the parameter in your global `id`?  I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @xDaevax Hi!  I'm sorry my example code is a little sloppy.  Id of 0 has a significance in this case, it would pass back the page in a "creation mode" if it is zero, of the specified layout based on the enum.  If it has a non-0 value, then it passes back the model with data for the specified layout based on the enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`screen != page`, so if the property on the anonymous type matches the parameter it will work:

```
public ActionResult ViewPage(int id, PageEnum screen) {
  var model = MyService.GetModelForTemplate(screen);
  return ("ViewPage", model);
}
```

Updated:  Created a empty application and it work flawlessly:

```
namespace MvcApplication6
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Test1",
                "PagesTypeOne/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", 
                      action = "Index", 
                      id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                      page = PageEnum.PageOne } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Test2",
                "PagesTypeTwo/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", 
                      action = "Index", 
                      id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                      page = PageEnum.PageOne } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", 
                      action = "Index", 
                      id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}

public enum PageEnum
{
    Undefined,
    PageOne,
    PageTwo
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace MvcApplication6.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ViewPage(int id, PageEnum page)
        {
            var debug = 1;  // break point

            return new EmptyResult();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I missed that in my example posted, however changing it does not seem to have worked; the enum is passed as null :(

Comment: Enums as you defined them can't be null (I don't see you using `Nullable<T>`).

Comment: sorry should have clarified, it throws "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'page' of non-nullable type...."

Comment: My code works just fine.  You may have the incorrect order for adding map routes.

Comment: Absolutely right, I had a routing issue with another defined path.  Commented out that path and it worked just fine.  Marking as accepted answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can make it completely dynamic with one route definition:

```
   // the route must be defined as the first route
   routes.MapRoute(
        name: "typeTwo",
        url: "{page}/ViewPage/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "ViewPage", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { page= getPageTypes() }
    );
```

the getPageTypes method:

```
private static string getPageTypes()
{
     var pageTypes = Enum.GetNames(typeof(PageEnum));
     return string.Join("|", pageTypes );
}
```

but **PagesTypeOne**/ViewPage/4 part must match the enum's name.

Comment: This is a cool solution.  Is there a way I can get that value at the controller action then to see which url the user pointed to?  It has implications for my viewmodel.

Comment: @SarahBourt yes, use Request.RawUrl or Request.Url